# Кодировка при чтении текста из JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing

Пробую реализовать запись текста из `JEditorPane`. При чтении текста методом `.getText()` и последующей записи в txt-файл кириллица преобразуется в символы вида `"&#1074"`. Как это можно побороть?

Полный текст класса:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.Size2DSyntax;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaPrintableArea;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PreviewPrinting extends JDialog{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 804726784085628551L;

    JEditorPane previewPane;
    JScrollPane scrlPane;
    JButton printBtn;
    JButton saveBtn;
    JButton cancelBtn;  
    JPanel mainPanel;
    private String text = "";
    //Конструктор. Принимает аргументы для подстановки в шаблон .html.
    public PreviewPrinting(String[] veriables){
        this.setSize(590, 490);
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setTitle("Предпросмотр и печать документа");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //Передаём текст для отображения и печати используя один из шаблонов.
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("report.htm"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            while (br.ready()){
                text+=br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception readEx)        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Файл шаблона не найден!", "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        /**/
        /**/
        /**/
        /**/
        /*Здесь должна быть обработка подстановки данных veriables в считанный шаблон.*/
        /**/
        /**/ 
        /**/ 
        /**/


        //Создаём компоненты окна и обработки событий нажатия кнопок.
        printBtn = new JButton("<html><b><u>Печать</u></b></html>");
        printBtn.setBounds(495, 372, 80, 20);
        printBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    //Устанавливаем размеры полей по умолчанию.
                    PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                    attrs.add(new MediaPrintableArea(10, 10, MediaSize.ISO.A4.getX( Size2DSyntax.MM ) - 20, MediaSize.ISO.A4.getY( Size2DSyntax.MM ) - 20, Size2DSyntax.MM));
                    //Печатаем.
                    previewPane.print(null, null, true, null, attrs, true);
                }
                catch (Exception printEx) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printEx.getMessage(), "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                dispose();
            }
        });

        saveBtn = new JButton("Сохранить");
        saveBtn.setBounds(495, 402, 80, 20);
        saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = previewPane.getText();
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                System.out.println(text);
                if (fc.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    try{
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fc.getSelectedFile()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        bw.write(text);
                        bw.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception saveEx) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, saveEx.getMessage(), "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }           
        });

        cancelBtn = new JButton("Отмена");
        cancelBtn.setBounds(495, 432, 80, 20);
        cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }           
        });

        previewPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", text);
        previewPane.setEditable(false);

        scrlPane = new JScrollPane(previewPane);
        scrlPane.setBounds(10, 10, 480, 443);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.add(scrlPane);
        mainPanel.add(printBtn);
        mainPanel.add(saveBtn);
        mainPanel.add(cancelBtn);

        this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно фрагмент кода получения текста и записи

Comment: Пардон, ещё не понял, как добавлять код. Добавил в текст вопроса.

Comment: видимо кодировка не та, а какую ты выбираешь при открытии файла?

Comment: Там смысл такой: есть файл html, я его открываю и считываю текст. Этот текст обрабатывается и передаётся в JEditorPane("text/html", text). На этом этапе всё ОК. Далее этот текст нужно сохранить в txt-файл. Тут-то и вылазят косяки. Сам файл в ANSI-кодировке. Пробовал менять, не помогает. Пробовал ставить CP1251 и UTF8 кодировки при считывании файла. Не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Трудно сказать в чем именно проблема, накидал по быстрому код. Файл должен сохраться в utf-8.

```
public class Solution extends JFrame {
private Solution() {
    super("title");

    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
    pane.setEditable(true);
    pane.setContentType("text/html");
    pane.setText("<h2>hello world</h2>");
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane), "Center");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.weighty = 0.0;

    getContentPane().add(panel, "South");

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    saveButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        String text = pane.getText();
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        System.out.println(text);
        if (fc.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fc.getSelectedFile()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
                bw.write(text);
            } catch (Exception saveEx) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, saveEx.getMessage(), "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    panel.add(saveButton);
    panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 4, 2, 4));

    getContentPane().add(panel, "East");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new Solution();
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    f.setSize(500, 400);
    f.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Comment: Попробовал добавить StandardCharsets.UTF_8. Не помогло. Я специально добавил строчку System.out.println(text); для контроля. В консоль тоже выводятся кракозябры. То есть проблема начинается уже при считывании текста из JEditorPane (в строчке String text = pane.getText();)

Comment: @Artik а в какой кодировке html файл? он в jeditpane нормально отображается?

Comment: В том-то и дело, в JEditPane отображается нормально. Файл в кодировке ANSI. А при считывании текста из JEditPane выдаёт &#... символы.

Comment: @Artik проблема в `HTMLWriter` он в методе `output()` все символы у которых код больше 127 конвертирует в &#код_символа. Чтобы такого не было, нужно или его переопределить, либо в `contentType` поменять `text/html` на `text`

Comment: Вся мякотка в том, что мне нужна html разметка. Я хочу с его помощью создать шаблоны для печати, в которые будут подставляться значения данных.

Comment: значит создавай кастомный

Comment: JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit() {

            public void write(Writer out, Document doc, int pos, int len) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
                HTMLWriter writer = new HTMLWriter(out, (HTMLDocument) doc) {
                    protected void output(char[] chars, int start, int length) throws IOException {
                       //реализация
                    }
                };
                writer.write();
            }
        });

Comment: Боюсь пока для меня это слишком сильное колдунство. Значит обойти никак?

Comment: @Artik Можно по тупому - просто сделать замену. например так.

Comment: private static String replaceAll(String text) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            int index;
            if (text.charAt(i) == '&' && (i + 1 < text.length() && text.charAt(i + 1) == '#') && (index = text.indexOf(";", i)) != -1) {
                result.append((char) Integer.parseInt(text.substring(i+2, index)));
                i = index;
            } else
                result.append(text.charAt(i));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

Comment: Мля!!111 Я как раз пришёл к такому выводу и копал в этом направлении. А тут Вы подкинули готовое решение. Гран мерси! Решение, канешна, не элегантное, но работает.

Comment: @Artik Если вопрос снят, отметь ансвер как принятый

Comment: Ищу, не пойму как это сделать. Я совсем недавно на сайте, многого не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй такую конструкцию

```
String text = new String(previewPane.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

PS
Провел эксперимент, [image: скрин с моего компа]
дайте пожалуйста по возможности полный код вашего приложения

Comment: Тоже попробовал. Не помогает.

Comment: Так стоп, как вы читаете файл?

Comment: Я добавил полный текст в вопрос. Правда, так и не понял, как красиво вставить текст кода.