# Проблема при получении русских символов из JEditorPane

Tags: java, utf-8

Есть такой JEditorPane.

```
JEditorPane textWorkZone = new JEditorPane();
textWorkZone.setContentType("text/html;charset=Cp1251");
textWorkZone.setText("Ехал <b>Грека</b> через реку");
System.out.println(textWorkZone.getText());
```

При попытке достать из него мой текст получаю ->

```
<html><head></head><body>&#1045;&#1093;&#1072;&#1083; <b>&#1043;&#1088;&#1077;&#1082;&#1072; 
&#1095;&#1077;&#1088;&#1077;&#1079; &#1088;&#1077;&#1082;&#1091;</body></html>
```

Как я могу получить мой текст с русскими символами? Наличие тегов обязательно.

Comment: В сети есть такое решение, сам не проверял: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028676/how-to-get-proper-unicode-string-no-enties-from-a-jeditorpane

Comment: Тут на сайте такая проблема уже обсуждалась: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554631/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-jeditorpane

Comment: @Leonis По 2ой ссылке решение так и не нашли, по первой сейчас попробую